# What can I use instead of char.to_i?

Tags: ruby

For an assignment I need to write a method named `get_integer_from_string` that will convert an input string to an integer.
I've completed it, but for one requirement:

- Please DO NOT use implicit or automatic type casting to solve this
  problem, i.e. atoi() in C, int()in Python, functions like parseInt()
  in Java or intval() in PHP

What can I replace `char.to_i` with in my code below to satisfy this requirement?

```
def get_integer_from_string(str, based=7)
  return 0 if (/^(?<num>\d+)$/ =~ str).nil?
  result = 0
  str.reverse.each_char.with_index do |char, index|
    tmp = char.to_i * based**index
    result += tmp
  end
  result rescue 0
end
```

Comment: May `base` be greater, than 10, e.g. 16?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you're overthinking this. Since `char` can only be one of ten different strings, just make a lookup table as a hash:

```
C_TO_I = {
  "0" => 0, "1" => 1, "2" => 2, "3" => 3, 
  "4" => 4, "5" => 5, "6" => 6, "7" => 7,
  "8" => 8, "9" => 9
}
```

Then just replace `char.to_i` in your code with `C_TO_I[char]`. To demonstrate:

```
char = "7"
p C_TO_I[char]
# => 7
```

Comment: `('0'..'9').map.with_index { |v, i| [v, i] }.to_h`

Comment: @mudasobwa so it will be like this 'code' def get_integer_from_string(str, based=7)
  return 0 if (/^(?<num>\d+)$/ =~ str).nil?
  result = 0
  str.reverse.each_char.with_index do |char, index|
    tmp = to-h* based**index
    result += tmp
  end
  result rescue 0
end

Comment: @AdelAlmaleh This question would better be addressed to this answer author; I would go with re-implementation of `to_i` (see my answer), which is safer for unusual bases.

Comment: @mudasobwa The block in your code is unnecessary. `with_index.to_h` works just fine.

Comment: @Jordan this answer still has glitches with converting `777` to 7-base. I see, that this is kinda out of scope of the original question, but anyway. PS. Yes, indeed, `to_h` is enough.

Comment: @jordan i know to_i convert values to integers but in this case still i didn't get your answers and you said use c_to_i but i never heard about it in ruby

Comment: @Jordan it's ruby again

Comment: `C_TO_I` is just the name of the constant that I stored the hash in. You could call it `CHARACTER_TO_INTEGER_LOOKUP_TABLE` if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

```
def my_to_i input, base
  ('0'...input).count.tap do |i|
    raise ArgumentError, 'Incorrect value in input' if i >= base || i < 0
  end
end
```

Here we re-implement `to_i` function using the fact that chars, representing digits, are located subsequently. `raise` clause takes care about invalid input, e. g. `8` when the base is `7`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for kicks, here's another way you might write your method:

```
C_TO_I = (?0..?9).each_with_index.to_h

def s_to_i(str, base=7, mag=0)
  return 0 if str.empty?
  C_TO_I[str[-1]] * base ** mag +
    s_to_i(str[0...-1], base, mag + 1)
end

str = "654"
p s_to_i(str) # => 333
```

Of course, the `C_TO_I` hash above will only work for base 10 and lower. You could go all the way up to base 36 with something like this instead:

```
C_TO_I = [ *?0..?9, *?a..?z ].each_with_index.to_h
```

Comment: `[ ?0..?9, ?a..?z ].flat_map(&:to_a)` ⇒ `[ *?0..?9, *?a..?z ]`.